# Force query to deliver duplicate results based off WHERE values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have been asked to add a few columns to a report based on account number.

The problem is that several accounts are listed more then once in this report.

The report has over 500 rows, but only 450 account numbers.

Is there a way to force my results to give me duplicate data?

Example:

```
SELECT
a.AccountNumber,
a.ProgramFlag,
a.ApplicationStatus

FROM
accountInfo as A

WHERE
a.AccountNumber in ('100','101','101','101','102','102','103')

ORDER BY
a.AccountNumber asc
```

Results:

```
AccountNumber | Program Flag | ApplicationStatus
------------------------------------------------
100           |      1       |     INSTALLED
101           |      0       |     CLOSED
102           |      1       |     INSTALLED
103           |      0       |     INSTALLED
```

Desired Results:

```
AccountNumber | Program Flag | ApplicationStatus
------------------------------------------------
100           |      1       |     INSTALLED
101           |      0       |     CLOSED
101           |      0       |     CLOSED
101           |      0       |     CLOSED
102           |      1       |     INSTALLED
102           |      1       |     INSTALLED
103           |      0       |     INSTALLED
```

The desired results would be much easier to add to a custom report by repeating all the information for accounts that appear more than once.  Especially one that is 500+ records.

Comment: I have joined the simple query with report query in the past, that's usually the easiest way.  However, I receive some reports that come from an outside organization that just happen to use our account numbers.  I don't have access to the original query or databases in that situation.  Mikael Eriksson's answer was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't add rows in a where clause but you can use your numbers in a derived table and join against that.

```
SELECT
  a.AccountNumber,
  a.ProgramFlag,
  a.ApplicationStatus
FROM
  dbo.accountInfo as A
INNER JOIN 
  (VALUES('100'),('101'),('101'),('101'),('102'),('102'),('103')) as T(AccountNumber)
ON
  A.AccountNumber = T.AccountNumber
ORDER BY
  a.AccountNumber asc;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a992a/1)